# PHP - Can't log out and show alert message at the same time

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP login system where you can delete your account/profile if you'd like to. When the user clicks on the button I want them to be logged out, their account to be deleted and an alert message (JavaScript) saying that their account has been deleted. The problem is that the alert message doesn't appear when I include the logout.php file. If I remove that line of code the alert message appears, but the user will still be logged in. How can I fix this?

Here is my code.

profile.php:

```
<form class="form" action="delete.php" method="post">
      <button type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your profile?')">Delete profile</button>
    </form>
```

delete.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["delete"])) {
  require_once 'dbh.inc.php';

  $deleteUser = "DELETE FROM users WHERE usersId='".$_SESSION["userid"]."'";

if ($conn->query($deleteUser) === TRUE) {
  echo "<script>alert('The profile has been deleted.');</script>";
  include 'logout.php';
} else {
  echo '<script>alert("Something went wrong: ")</script>';
}

} else {
  header("location: ../index.php");
  exit();
}
```

logout.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location: ../index.php");
exit();
```

Comment: You can not create output (JS code), _and_ redirect elsewhere at the same time. (Well technically, you can - but the browser will not _interpret_ any JS code you send it, while you are saying “go look somewhere else” at the same time.) You could f.e. just redirect to the index.php with an additional GET parameter - and then inside the index.php, you check if that parameter is set, and if so, you output your specific message/JS code there then.

Comment: Inside logout.php your ``header("location: ../index.php");`` this line executes at the server level and thus your **alert** is not executing as it will execute on the browser, not at the server level. But you are redirecting to the index page. PS - Try to avoid a mixture of two different languages.  Better to use them separately and bridge the connection between both using AJAX.

Comment: You also can't call `header()` after you've started outputting things (like your echo). All `header()`-calls need to be called _before_ any output at all.

Comment: Pass a query string parameter to the logout page indicating that account deletion has occurred. The logout page can then decide to display a message about it if that parameter is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add redirection along with the `alert()` in js rather than doing in php.

```
echo "<script>alert('The profile has been deleted.'); window.location.href='logout.php';</script>";
```

This will show alert then redirect to logout.php

Answer (score 0):

try change the following code:

From:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location: ../index.php");
exit();
```

To:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

echo "<script>alert('The profile has been deleted.');</script>";
header("location: ../index.php");
exit();
```

Comment: remember to comment out the alert function in ur if else statement

Comment: This would just make the `header` not function.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. The message still doesn't appear. :(